# Cannot Access LocalHost Using PostgresSQL on Presto

Tags: presto

I have Presto installed on my Mac.  I also have PostgreSQL.  Both are installed locally.  I only intend to use them locally. Presto is working fine.

I followed the documentation listed here:

https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/postgresql.html

```
connector.name=postgresql
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://example.net:5432/database
connection-user=root
connection-password=secret
```

Is there any command I can use in PostgreSQL to get the correct "connection-url".  I have been trying the following, but it does not connect:

```
 connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080:5432/MyDataBase
```

As well, is there a driver I should be downloading?  I have been trying for weeks, but cannot get a connection running.

Comment: Did you try `connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the only issue you had, but in your connection URL you're specifying two ports i.e. 8080 as well as 5432.

Postgres generally runs on 5432 by default so I think you'd just need:

```
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDataBase
```